# How to get number of threads which was created in "black box" on linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

Let me clarify my question with code:

```
int main()
{
    // call for some function which creates threads
    i_create_some_threads();

    // I can get PID
    pid_t pid = getpid();

    // need to get all threads here
    // ???
}
```

I know about parsing `/proc/PID/tasks/` but looking for a way to do it in my program and without parsing of directories/files.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Perhaps you should collect and retain the ID of each new thread as you create it, rather than trying to divine them all later...

Comment: Actually I don't create them by myself. As I wrote `i_create_some_threads()` is a black box for me.

Answer (score 0):

Something involving

```
ps -o nlwp <pid>
```

may be what you want. -o means user defined output format, nlwp is number of threads. This will give you the output like this:

```
 NLWP
    6
```

Just try to execute that command and manipulate its output in your code.

Comment: Thank you! But I look for something like I do with PID, getting it using standard function.